# Update column with return value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to split columns in a table into another table and use a foreign key to point the row in the original table to the new table.

How can I copy the column data to the other table and update each row with the returned identity from the insert into the new table ?

Heres what I have so far :

```
insert into tbl_2(col_6,col_7) select col_2, col_3 from tbl_1 returning col_5
```

I am using postgres a my DB.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a CTE.  If I understand correctly:

```
with i as (
      insert into tbl_2(col_6,col_7)
          select col_2, col_3
          from tbl_1
      returning tbl_2_id
     )
update tbl_1
    set tbl_2_id = i.tbl_2_id
    from i
    where tbl_1.col_6 = i.col_6 and tbl_1.col_7 = i.col_7;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just added a temporary column to the new table and added the primary key from the first table and did a second update statement to add each foreign key back into the first table.